# Casting: What is the difference btw. T(value) and (T)value for built-in types?

Tags: c++, casting

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [C++ cast syntax styles](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32168/c-cast-syntax-styles)
>   [What is the difference between (type)value and type(value) ?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1652396/what-is-the-difference-between-typevalue-and-typevalue)

In C++, when explicitly converting one built-in type to another, you can write:

```
int x = (int)c;
int x = int(c);
int d = (double)f;
int d = double(f);
```

I known that `(T)v` is a C-style cast, and I think the other syntax isn't technically a cast, but what is the other syntax called and what are its semantics? (And where to use which?)

Comment: @Tomalak: Yes, my bad; I copy-pasted the wrong question #...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`T(value)` is actually an initialization of the type `T`, and because it's an initialization, an implicit type conversion can take place if the type of `value` and `T` are convertible. If `T` is a class-object, then one of it's constructors is called, either a default constructor that takes a single value and `T` and `value` are implicitly convertible types, or the copy constructor with the same condition that the two types are implicitly convertible. `(T)value`, as you've noted, is a C-style cast from the type of `value`, to the type `T`.  Both in the end though are pretty much doing the same thing under the hood since if you did

```
T var1 = T(value);
T var2 = (T)value;
```

you'd get the exact same result, that is both create/return an object of type `T` which an be used to initialize an l-value of type `T`.