# What does the C++ standard say about the difference between casting from type a to type b, and instantiating/Constructing type b?

Tags: c++, casting, constructor

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is the difference between (type)value and type(value)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1652396/what-is-the-difference-between-typevalue-and-typevalue)

If you have a function that takes an argument of type b, but at the call site you only have a variable of type a.  Is there a difference between casting the function parameter from a to b, and constructing type b.

The specific example I am interested in is when there is no user defined cast operator, but there is a single argument constructor.

Example:

Function definition:

```
void DoWork(const B &arg1);
```

In my specific example type a is `const char *`

Call site:

```
DoWork((B)"Hello");
```

vs

```
DoWork(B("Hello"));
```

B class definition

```
class B
{
public:
    B() : m_szValue(){}
    B(const char *szValue) { strcpy (m_szValue, szValue); }
private:
    char m_szValue[MAX_VALUE_LEN + 1];
};
```

Comment: And notice how that question is _so_ much clearer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Writing a C-style cast `(T)x`, where `x` is of type `U`, more or less tries the following in order:

1. If `T` and `U` are of class type, look for a conversion operator `U::operator T() const` or a one-argument constructor `T::T(U)`.
2. If `T` and `U` are primitive types, apply the standard value conversions (int to double, etc.).
3. `reinterpret_cast<T>(x)`.

Note that you mustn't have *both* a conversion operator and implicit conversion construction, though, or the call will be ambiguous.

[*Correction/Clarification*:] There is no difference between `T(x)` and `(T)x`.[/] You can even say `DoWork("Hello");` on account of the *implicit* conversion provided by the one-argument constructor. (Do disallow this sneaky behaviour, declare the constructor `explicit`, as is often a good idea for one-argument constructors.)

Comment: This is misleading / wrong: in fact, there is *no* difference at all between the C-style cast and the function-style cast (except for syntax). They are identical in every respect; not only in OP’s code, but everywhere.

Comment: @Konrad: Hm... which aspect of this is *wrong*, though? The C-style cast achieves what any of the listed constructions achieve, don't they? The point is that it subsumes various conversions as well as reinterpretation, which you can control explicitly with the C++ constructions.

Comment: @Your answer strongly implies that `T(x)` sometimes has a different meaning than `(T)x`. At least that’s how I would understand your answer. You explicitly said “ *in your code* there is no difference” (emphasis mine) and while that’s true, it’s also an irrelevant detail. There is no difference, full stop.

Comment: @Konrad: I see, good point, let me reword that.

Comment: @Konrad: Check it out now, I hope this is more accurate!

Comment: Already checked, already voted up.