# uint8_t can't be printed with cout

Tags: c++, cout, unsigned-char, uint8t, c++-faq

I wrote a simple program that sets a value to a variable and then prints it, but it is not working as expected. My program has only two lines of code:

```cpp
uint8_t a = 5;

cout << "value is " << a << endl;
```

The output of this program is `value is` , i.e., it prints blank for `a`.

When I change `uint8_t` to `uint16_t`, the above code works like a charm.

I use Ubuntu 12.04 (Precise Pangolin), 64-bit, and my compiler version is:

```
gcc version 4.6.3 (Ubuntu/Linaro 4.6.3-1ubuntu5)
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [uint8\_t iostream behavior](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15296661/uint8-t-iostream-behavior)

Comment: [cout not printing unsigned char](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15585267/995714)

Comment: You'd really think this would "just work". RIP C++ type system. Isn't this the whole point of types?

Answer (score 234, accepted):

It doesn't really print a blank, but most probably the ASCII character with value 5, which is non-printable (or invisible). There's a number of [invisible ASCII character codes](http://www.cs.tut.fi/%7Ejkorpela/chars/c0.html), most of them below value 32, which is the blank actually.

You have to convert `a` to `unsigned int` to output the numeric value, since `ostream& operator<<(ostream&, unsigned char)` tries to output the visible character value.

```
uint8_t a = 5;

cout << "value is " << unsigned(a) << endl;
```

Comment: Since C style casts are frowned upon, wouldn't it be better to do a static_cast?

Comment: It should be **converted** to `int`. A cast is one way to do that, but not the only way. `+aa` also works.

Comment: @PeteBecker Like this: int(aa) ?

Comment: That, too; it's a function-style cast.

Comment: @rubenvb I left it to the function style cast, which seems to give the best balance for intuitive reading and loquacious code. Personally I don't have a problem to use simply C-style casts for such a situation.

Comment: isn't int(var) and (int)var actually the same thing?

Comment: @paulm No. c-style casts are discouraged for c++ for a number of reasons.

Comment: so then what is int(var) doing vs (int)var?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1652396/what-is-the-difference-between-typevalue-and-typevalue looks like you still have a C cast here...

Comment: @paulm `(int)var` lets you just cast (away) anything, without letting the compiler know about you doing illegal or silly thngs.

Comment: See the linked question using type(var) is the same as (type)var its the *same* as the C cast - try it out with const etc, it removes it!

Comment: @paulm _'looks like you still have a C cast here'_ No. I read it, it's just if `int(var)` is valid the _effect_ is the same. It's not the main topic of **this** Q/A though.

Comment: Exactly, so why bother replacing the C cast when static_cast is safer as it won't also apply const_cast or the effects of reinterpret_cast?

Comment: @paulm `static_cast<int>(var)` would be perfectly OK for me (as I mentioned), it just looks ridiculous(ly long to type) for others ...

Comment: The response "No. c-style casts are discouraged for c++ for a number of reasons." to "isn't int(var) and (int)var actually the same thing?" sure makes it seem as if you didn't realise `int(var)` and `(int)var` have exactly the same meaning. `int(var)` is discouraged in exactly those cases where `(int)var` is, for exactly the same reasons, *because* it means exactly the same thing. (I can understand why you'd go for it here anyway, though, so I'm not saying you need to use `static_cast`. I just think the comment trail here got a bit unnecessarily confusing.)

Comment: @hvd Of course I was aware that this is exactly the same. It was just a stupid discussion what the correct (and shortest) cast style should be.

Comment: @PeteBecker - Please forgive my ignorance.... What is *`+aa`* called (from your statement *"+aa also works"*).

Comment: @jww - it's a unary plus. Just like unary minus (`-aa`), except that it doesn't affect the value. But it promotes smaller types to `int`, as do all arithmetic operators. (and there's nothing to forgive; it's rather obscure)

Comment: unsigned(x)... looks like i should start collecting a list of non obvious subtleties in C/C++ that are likely to blow the minds of those who never seen them before.

Comment: @DouglasDaseeco How so? It's pretty clear what happens.

Comment: The `+aa` style is idiomatic in JavaScript (which does something different).  I don't see the unary `+` used much in C++, even in this "apply the usual arithmetic promotion", which in this situation is an appropriate and suitable use-case.

Comment: `+aa` style is the best when you work with templated code that needs to handle number from uint8_t to uint64_t.

Comment: @PeteBecker variable size will increase to 4 byte from 1 byte. I want a 1 byte variable. any help?

Comment: @Sadegh The cast doesn't involve any _"variables"_, just register operations, which won't affect your stack or otherwise memory management.

Comment: Aren't we arguing about the wrong thing? This shouldn't even _need_ to be casted (intuitively). An unsigned int shouldn't be printed as an ASCII character by default...I'm curious if the reason for this is just "C heritage", or if there's a different/deeper reason?

Comment: @MattMessersmith it's not  `unsigned int` in question here.

Answer (score 82):

Adding a unary + operator before the variable of any primitive data type will yield a printable numerical value instead of an ASCII character (in case of char type).

```cpp
uint8_t a = 5;
cout << "value is " << +a << endl; // value is 5
```

This works because `+a` result in `a` being [promoted to `int`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/conversion#Integer_promotions).

Comment: That's nice, but why doesn't c++ treat `uint8_t` as `unsigned char` which would be numerical values?

Comment: @R1S8K this is because while `uint8_t` is just a type def of `unsigned char`, `unsigned char` itself is handled by `ostream` just like `char` and prints its ASCII value.

Comment: @Harsh Thanks man ! so it's a type def of `unsigned char` that explains a lot. So the only integer is `int`, right ?

Comment: @R1S8K Well, the smallest integer type would be `short int` which takes up 2 bytes. There are a few other variations of the integer type as well.

Comment: @Harsh Also I think when programming and declaring variables, it doesn't matter if I declare a variable that would deal only with small numbers not exceeding like 250 with a big register size like `long` or `int` because the compiler would optimize the use of RAM or flash according to what fills that register, am I right ?

Comment: @R1S8K Hmm... I am not sure; but I am strongly inclined towards that not being the case. :)

Comment: @Harsh Yes you're right, I did a small test in Arduino IDE, and declared a variable `long` and initialize it with a small number, big number and nothing, it's all the same and nothing has been taken from the RAM/Flash !! But I didn't write any code beside setup and loop functions, I think there has to be some code using the variables to be counted from the RAM or the flash if it's assigned with something like `const dataType variableName[] PROGMEM = {data0, data1, data3…​};`

Comment: @R1S8K - just because you init a variable to a small number doesn't mean it will stay that way.  It's very unlikely that the compiler can determine all possible values a variable will hold for a given program (and that they fit in a smaller size than you declared), so I'd be surprised if they actually optimized this, except possibly in cases where a variable was never set and such.

Comment: @DavidLjungMadisonStellar Yes, I think the point would be if the variable hasn't been set, and probably the compiler won't optimize the variable to fit the value because that variable could change to any value during operation time so the variable size is as is.

Comment: @R1S8K exactly.  And you can fundamentally prove that it's impossible to know (for a general purpose program) all the possible values all variables will hold (and hence their size).  That's *why* (static) lanaguages that are concerned about memory usage give you different sized integers.  Dynamic languages can resize for you on the fly.

Comment: How does this work?

Comment: This solution should be up-voted more because it is much more flexible than casting to (int) as is suggested in the other solution. The reason is simple: casting for fixed type (int) works well when you know for sure that the type that you are trying to output is int8_t. However, when you write a template class or function, you do not know the type upfront and casting to fixed type like (int) can lead to undesired behavior if the template user instantiates it with an integer type larger than int (for example with int64_t). Adding unary + does not have this issue.

Answer (score 61):

`uint8_t` will most likely be a `typedef` for `unsigned char`. The `ostream` class has a special overload for `unsigned char`, i.e. it prints the character with the number 5, which is non-printable, hence the empty space.

Comment: I wish the standard really treated std::uint8_t as a separate type and not just a friggin' typedef. There is no sane reason to apply character-semantics to these types when used in conjunction with stream objects.

Answer (score 21):

- Making use of [ADL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Argument-dependent_name_lookup) (Argument-dependent name lookup):

  ```
  #include <cstdint>
  #include <iostream>
  #include <typeinfo>

  namespace numerical_chars {
  inline std::ostream &operator<<(std::ostream &os, char c) {
      return std::is_signed<char>::value ? os << static_cast<int>(c)
                                         : os << static_cast<unsigned int>(c);
  }

  inline std::ostream &operator<<(std::ostream &os, signed char c) {
      return os << static_cast<int>(c);
  }

  inline std::ostream &operator<<(std::ostream &os, unsigned char c) {
      return os << static_cast<unsigned int>(c);
  }
  }

  int main() {
      using namespace std;

      uint8_t i = 42;

      {
          cout << i << endl;
      }

      {
          using namespace numerical_chars;
          cout << i << endl;
      }
  }
  ```

  output:

  ```
  *
  42
  ```
- A custom stream manipulator would also be possible.
- The unary plus operator is a neat idiom too (`cout << +i << endl`).

Comment: Isn't [KISS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/KISS_principle) still a valid paradigm??

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ of course, but don't forget: [Everything Should Be Made as Simple as Possible, But Not Simpler](http://quoteinvestigator.com/2011/05/13/einstein-simple/)

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ anyway, this is here just to provide an option, one can choose to just include a header for that and then add a using statement once, or opt to cast all over the place where it's needed.

Comment: Another option, yeah! **But:** The block wise `using namespace` statements, etc. look really clumsy vs. a pragmatic version simply casting the (`unsigned`) `char` values to int for output.

Comment: LOC or different metrics might be valued in the eye of your **stakeholder** I think ;) ... You'll need to instrument all of your code with these statements you show, instead of just fix a small part using the `int()` cast!!

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ of course, but, for me at last, LOC argument doesn't count in favor of casting all over the place when it's the case. One would use such a tool when, precisely, there's a case of several casts and it gets daunting to apply so many of them.

Comment: I don't believe that's really feasible for writing production ready code **productively**. My co-workers would **kill** me for proposing such solution in case of question!

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ ok, keep doing tons of c style casts in c++ code then, anyone is free to be productive the way it is, in the environment that he/she fits the most.

Comment: The problem with your solution is, that you'll really need to open a scoped code block and put the `using special_namespace` statement to enclose each and every access to the right `operator<<()` function implementation. Putting a global `using special_namespace;` won't cover all cases reasonably transparent, but ask for namespace collisions.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ seriously? functional style cast, also, is just c style casting. changing one from the other doesn't help in anything in leaving the realm of C, check: http://stackoverflow.com/a/4775807/1000282. pete-becker commented this on your answer too, but you seem to have missed his last comment.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/46392/discussion-between---and-pepper-chico)

Comment: This solution is very elegant & effective, because it works with templates. In facts, that's the only solution I've spotted that works for me.
One caveat though, the first function has a bug, because 'os' is bound to a single type, and therefore, either the signed or the unsigned value will be sent to the wrong version of operator<<(). The fix is simple enough:
`return std::is_signed<char>::value ? os << static_cast<int>(c) : os << static_cast<unsigned int>(c);`

Comment: @GeorgesBerenger correct!, indeed I missed that ternary result. Glad you liked, it seems love or hate :)

Comment: Nice solution. However, you probably want to do something similar for `std::istream` to avoid any surprises with reading from an input stream

Comment: Agree with @GeorgesBerenger: This is the only means by which a template type, which may be char or unsigned char (int8_t or uint8_t), will work properly. And it was the solution I was looking for. Thank you.

Comment: *"Making use of ADL (Argument-dependent name lookup):"* - not that it's otherwise important, but ADL is not utilised by this answer... the `operator<<` overloads are found using normal namespace searching if and only if that `using namespace numerical_chars;` has been explicitly specified.  ADL is relevant when one of the function/operator argument types is in the same namespace as the function/operator - in your code, `std::ostream` is not in `numerical_chars`, and the char types aren't either of course.

Comment: This seems to be the only solution that properly outputs a 2-digit hexa: `uint8_t c = 33; os << "0x" << std::hex << c;` All other solutions add extra digits.

Answer (score 20):

It's because the output operator treats the `uint8_t` like a `char` (`uint8_t` is usually just an alias for `unsigned char`), so it prints the character with the ASCII code (which is the most common character encoding system) `5`.

See e.g. [this reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ostream/operator_ltlt2).

Comment: Why? the C compiler treats it as a number. I think C++ is different at this point.

Comment: @PerchEagle If you read the linked reference you will see that the operator is overloaded for both `signed` and `unsigned` characters (beyond plain `char` which in C++ is really a third separate type). So if `uint8_t` is an alias for `unsigned char` (very likely) that's what will be used.

Comment: Could you check my answer on this thread and tell me if my answer is right or not? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15585267/cout-not-printing-unsigned-char, my answer is before the last one. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 8):

`cout` is treating `aa` as `char` of ASCII value `5` which is an unprintable character, try typecasting to `int` before printing.

Comment: variable size will increase to 4 byte from 1 byte. I want a 1 byte variable. any help?

Answer (score 6):

The `operator<<()` overload between `std::ostream` and `char` is a non-member function. You can explicitly use the member function to treat a `char` (or a `uint8_t`) as an `int`.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstddef>

int main()
{
   uint8_t aa=5;

   std::cout << "value is ";
   std::cout.operator<<(aa);
   std::cout << std::endl;

   return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
value is 5
```

Answer (score 3):

As others said before the problem occurs because standard stream treats signed char and unsigned char as single characters and not as numbers.

Here is my solution with minimal code changes:

```
uint8_t aa = 5;

cout << "value is " << aa + 0 << endl;
```

Adding `"+0"` is safe with any number including floating point.

For integer types it will change type of result to `int` if `sizeof(aa) < sizeof(int)`. And it will not change type if `sizeof(aa) >= sizeof(int)`.

This solution is also good for preparing `int8_t` to be printed to stream while some other solutions are not so good:

```
int8_t aa = -120;

cout << "value is " << aa + 0 << endl;
cout << "bad value is " << unsigned(aa) << endl;
```

Output:

```
value is -120
bad value is 4294967176
```

P.S. Solution with ADL given by pepper_chico and πάντα ῥεῖ is really beautiful.

Comment: variable size will increase to 4 byte from 1 byte. I want a 1 byte variable. any help?

Comment: Ingenious, I have a templated << operator for uint8_t and float, and this one works perfectly

Answer (score 1):

This is one of the known problems with iostreams that interpret `unsigned char` (and `uint8_t` which is usually an alias to `unsigned char`) as a [code unit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Character_encoding#Terminology) rather than an integer type. It has been fixed in C++20 [`std::format`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/format/format). For example ([godbolt](https://www.godbolt.org/z/5rnz5a1TP)):

```cpp
uint8_t a = 5;
std::cout << std::format("value is {}\n", a);
```

prints

```
value is 5
```

In C++23 this can be further simplified to:

```cpp
uint8_t a = 5;
std::print("value is {}\n", a);
```

**Disclaimer**: I'm the author of C++20 `std::format` and C++23 `std::print`.