# Proper type conversion for printing bytes

Tags: c++, rust

I'm trying to re-implement the [business card ray tracer](http://fabiensanglard.net/rayTracing_back_of_business_card/) in rust for fun and profit.  As far as I can tell all of the logic is in place, but for the life of me I can't figure out how correctly convert from my floating point values to the RGB bytes that the ppm file format expects.  In the original code (C++), it looks like this:

```
printf("%c%c%c",(int)p.x,(int)p.y,(int)p.z);
```

where `p` is a 3-d vector of floats representing an RGB value.  I didn't have much luck with `print!`, so after much tweaking I wrote the equivalent expression as:

```
let mut out = io::stdout();
out.write(&[(p.x as u8),(p.x as u8),(p.x as u8)]);
```

However, the output is way off (I can post it if you really want, but suffice it to say that the correct output has plenty of non-printable characters, while my version is quite printable).  I honestly don't understand the nuances of type conversion for either language.  Anyone care to lend a hand?

**Edit:** [full source](https://gist.github.com/axelmagn/10946425) (note that I use floats as vector attributes)

Comment: Rather `printf("%d%d%d",(int)p.x,(int)p.y,(int)p.z);`?? Also related (especially for c++): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19562103/uint8-t-cant-be-printed-with-cout/19562163#19562163

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code seems basically correct (assuming you didn't mean p.x three times).
Here's a small program showing printing an RGB struct containing u32s as bytes, which I verified works as expected (prints ABC\n)

```
struct RGB {
  x: u32,
  y: u32,
  z: u32
}

fn main() {
  let  p = RGB{ x:65, y:66, z:67};
  let mut out = std::io::stdout();
  out.write([p.x as u8, p.y as u8, p.z as u8, 10]);
}
```

Comment: I've added my full source in a link.  Could it be that my struct uses f64 for its xyz attributes?