# Behavior of cout << hex with uint8 and uint16

Tags: c++, hex, stdout

I'm noticing that `cout << hex` is giving me strange results, and I cannot find anywhere that answers why.  What I am doing is simply assigning some values to both a `uint8_t` and `uint16_t` and then attempting to write them to stdout.  When I run this:

```
uint8_t a = 0xab;
uint16_t b = 0x24de;
cout << hex << a << endl;
cout << hex << b << endl;
```

That I get the result:

```
$./a.out

24de
$
```

with no value displayed for the uint8_t.  What could be causing this?  I didn't think there wouldn't be a cout implementation for one type for not the other.

Comment: BTW `hex` is sticky, once you do it on the first line then it persists until you set `dec`.

Comment: possible duplicate of [uint8\_t can't be printed with cout](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19562103/uint8-t-cant-be-printed-with-cout)

Answer (score 25, accepted):

`std::uint8_t` is an alias for `unsigned char`:

```
typedef unsigned char uint8_t;
```

So the overload of the inserter that takes a `char&` is chosen, and the ASCII representation of `0xab` is written, which could technically vary by your operating system, as `0xab` is in the range of Extended ASCII.

You have to cast it to an integer:

```
std::cout << std::hex << static_cast<int>(a) << std::endl;
```

Comment: Try to never use a forced cast when an implicit conversion is sufficient.

Comment: @BenVoigt Is an implicit conversion attainable in this expression?

Comment: @BenVoigt The trick with `+` is nice, but in my opinion the cast shows clearer intent and is less confusing to anyone looking at the code that might not know the trick.

Comment: @RetiredNinja: Then feel free to use `0u + a`, where it obviously has to produce a result of at least the same size as the larger operand (`unsigned int`).  The thing is that if the type of `a` ever changes, the addition operator won't suddenly start doing something stupid, like a cast might.

Comment: @Ben Voigt could you please elaborate: in what kind of situation would a cast do something stupid ? I can't figure out. (I would also do a cast here and I'd like to understand why this could possibly be wrong)

Comment: @kebs: Say you change the variable to `unsigned long long a = 0x123456789abcdefULL;` Or `double a = 1.6;`  Now the cast will throw away part of the value, but either unary or binary `+` will print the entire value.

Comment: @Ben Voigt thank you, much clearer now. Indeed, I didn't consider this case where the original type is "larger" than the casted type.

Answer (score 14):

The other answers are correct about the reason.  The simplest fix is:

```
cout << hex << +a << endl;
```

Demonstration: http://ideone.com/ZHHAHX

It works because operands undergo integer promotion.

Comment: C++ never fails to surprise me

Answer (score 7):

`uint8_t` is an alias for `unsigned char`. You're essentially printing a character with the value `0xab`, which might be an invalid character depending on your encoding.

This would be solvable by casting it to another integer type, converting its value to a string in advance or writing some sort of a wrapper class that implements `std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream&, const ClassName&)`.