# Reading a Binary file and interpreting the data

Tags: c++, binary, ascii, binaryfiles

My objective is to read in data from a binary file and ultimately store the bits in 32bit slices. I have found a few different methods of reading binary in C++ but am not sure which is the best option and my main issue is that when outputting the data after having stored it I am not accessing individual bits but am displaying ASCII characters it seems.

```
int main(int argc, const char *argv[])
{

std::vector<char> memblock;
int i=0;
        ::std::ifstream in(argv[1], ::std::ios::binary);
        while (in) {
              char c;
              in.get(c);
              if (in) {
                 memblock.push_back(int(c));
                i++;
                  //::std::cout << "Read a " << int(c) << "\n";
              }
           }
std::cout << "The contents of memblock are:";
  for (std::vector<char>::iterator it = memblock.begin(); it != memblock.end(); ++it)
    std::cout << ' ' << *it;
  std::cout << '\n';
return 0;
}
```

And also:

```
streampos size;
      char * memblock;

      ifstream file ("path", ios::in|ios::binary|ios::ate);
      if (file.is_open())
      {
        size = file.tellg();
        memblock = new char [size];
        file.seekg (0, ios::beg);
        file.read (memblock, size);
        file.close();

        cout << "the entire file content is in memory";

       for(int i =0; i<10; i++){
           cout << memblock[i+2000];
       }
      }
```

Is there an advantage to each approach? Or is there an even better method? Also how do I make sure to store the actual bit values or binary data from the binary file? Thank you

Comment: possible duplicate of [uint8\_t can't be printed with cout](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19562103/uint8-t-cant-be-printed-with-cout)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to be reading 32bit integers, not `char`:

```
uint32_t * memblock;
ifstream file ("path", ios::in|ios::binary|ios::ate);
   if (file.is_open())
   {
       size = file.tellg();
       memblock = new unit32_t [size / 4 + (size % 4 == 0 ? 0 : 1)];
       file.seekg (0, ios::beg);
       file.read (reinterpret_cast<char*>(memblock), size);
       file.close();

       cout << "the entire file content is in memory";

       for(int i =0; i<size/4; i++){
            cout << memblock[i];
       }
    }
```

Comment: Never mind. But there's still a typo in the allocation statement.

Comment: Why do you cast memblock as char* when reading?

Comment: @JohnSmith because `ifstream::read` wants a `char` pointer passed in.

Comment: Note: If `size` is not a multiple of 4, insufficient memory is allocated.  Maybe `memblock = new unit32_t [(size + 3)/4];`.

Comment: Sorry so pedantic, but now if `size` is not a multiple of 4, the last `cout << memblock[i]` is not well defined as `memblock[size32-1]` was only partially read by `file.read`.  Hmmm `if (size % 4) OpenCanOfWorms()`.

Comment: @chux ok, fixed it to only `cout` fully read intergers

Answer (score 1):

You **are** reading the actual binary content. Printing it via `cout` yields ascii characters because `cout` is designed for printing strings when passing `char` values unless told otherwise. Also if you want to store it in 32bit slices you should not use `char` but a 32bit datatype instead. Try `uint32_t`. Don't forget to adjust the size then since file size is given in bytes but `uint32_t` has four bytes.

In order to test whether the `N`th bit (where `N` starts at 0) is set in some integer variable you could define the following macro:

```
#define IS_BIT_SET(v, N) ( (v) & ( 1<<(N) ) )
bool bit12Set = IS_BIT_SET(v, 12);
```

Or use `std::bitset` if you need more comfort.

Comment: Thank you, is there a way to directly print the bits then? Or a way to access individual bits?

Comment: If you want to inspect bits individually you'd have to use the bitwise operators together with masking.