# Standard Input for Unsigned Character

Tags: c++, stdin, unsigned-char

I am trying to send unsigned characters through a program, and I would like to be able to get the numbers through standard input (ie std::cin).  For example when I type 2 I would like it send ☻ (unsigned char 2).  when I use the code:

```
 std::cout << "Enter values: ";
            {
                unsigned char d;
                unsigned char e = 2;
                std::cin >> d;
                WriteFile(file, &d, 1, &written, NULL);
                std::cout << "d= " << d << "\n"; 
                std::cout << "e= " << e;
            }
```

I get

```
 Enter values: 2
 d=2
 e=☻
```

Can anyone tell me why d is being interpreted Incorrectly as unsigned char 50 while e is being interpreted correctly as unsigned char 2?

And of course after your explanation can You explain how to get User input and convert it so that I send 2 rather than '2'.

Comment: `2` is the integer with value 2, not the character `'2'`

Comment: This also has nothing to do with signed-ness.

Comment: `e` very correctly has the value `2`, while `d`, indeed also correctly, has the value `'2'`. Those are quite different values.

Comment: possible duplicate of [uint8\_t can't be printed with cout](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19562103/uint8-t-cant-be-printed-with-cout)

Comment: The only reason that is a duplicate is because that question, too, displays a complete lack of understanding the difference between an integer and a character literal.

Comment: @BartvanNierop I understand the difference I just don't know how to get the integer from the standard input.

Comment: @jeffpkamp Then you should update your question to reflect that the value of `d` is _incorrect_, and the value of `e` is in fact what you're looking for.

Comment: @BartvanNierop I think that's explicitly stated twice in my question.  Any ideas on how I can get 2 from the standard input rather than '2'?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because `std::cin >> d;` reads by default a `char` type, so the input `2` translates into the character `2` (with ASCII code 50) and not the character represented by the ASCII code 2. This is a normal behaviour, otherwise trying to read numbers from `cin` will end up being a mess.

On the other hand, in `unsigned char e = 2;` you explicitly assign a value (`2`) to the variable, so the compiler blindly assigns it to `e`.

You probably want this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    string myString;
    cin >> myString;
    char c = atoi(myString.c_str());
    cout << c << endl;
}
```

Comment: okay, I figured as much.  So how can I get the ascii value 2 from a console input without using alt+2?

Comment: @jeffpkamp You don't. It's not a printable character.

Comment: @jeffpkamp I believe the standard says that `std::cin` is text-mode, so I do not think you can read ascii directly. I am not sure though. What you can do is to read it as a number, then convert the character that represents the number into an integer. Can use for example `char c = atoi(myString.c_str())` to convert a previously read string `myString` into an integer. See the code I just posted above.

Comment: Why go through `std::string`, instead of going through `int`? This seems needlessly complicated.

Answer (score 0):

When you enter `2` via `std::cin`, it's correctly interpreted as the character literal `'2'`.

You should replace

```
unsigned char e = 2;
```

with

```
unsigned char e = '2';
```