# Symbol id instead of the actual symbol

Tags: c++, symbols

```
vector<vector<int>> mapVector(maxX, vector<int>(maxY));
char* mapBuffer = new char[mapString.size() + 1];
...
mapVector[i][j] = mapBuffer[y];
...
```

`mapBuffer[i][j]` contains the '#" symbol but after the "`mapVector[i][j] = mapBuffer[y]`"
`mapVector[i][j]` contans number "35". Why is it passing on the id instead of the symbol?

Comment: You have not told much about how you are looking at the data, but the ASCII character number 35 is '#' if you ask to see it as a character you will see '#' if you ask to see it as a numeric value you will see 35.

Comment: Well, how do I do that?

Comment: _"Well, how do I do that?"_ [See here for example please](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19562103/uint8-t-cant-be-printed-with-cout/19562163#19562163)

Comment: @НикитаПогуца Show us how you did it till now

Comment: Why do you want to keep chars in int vector?

Answer (score -1):

Here is how to see the data using printf:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main (int argc, char **argv){
    char test='#';
    printf("test %c %d\n", test,test);
    return 0;

}
```

%c renders as a char
%d renders as an int

(The above is in C but that part of C that will be compiled by a C++ compiler)

So in your code if you change your vector to a vector of char you will not have the issue:

```
 vector<vector<char>> mapVector(maxX, vector<char>(maxY));
 char* mapBuffer = new char[mapString.size() + 1];
 ...
 mapVector[i][j] = mapBuffer[y];
 ...
```

Comment: I am not 100% sure that it works on big endian architecture without a cast. But I compiled and ran it before I posted it on a little endian x86 box.

Comment: Just built and ran it on a PPC Mac running OSX still works, that is big endian.

Comment: why not use C++, which OP is using?

Comment: C++ is a super set of C and I was trying to show something very simple. The OP did not show what the type mapVector was just that it has two subscripts, I don't want to explicitly fix their code in a cut and paste way, I just want to show them what they are seeing and give them a clue as to how to fix it.

Comment: first: mapVector is vector<vector<int> (which is C++ stl), second: C++ is not a super set of C, it's a different language (which happens to be compatible with C), third: question is tagged C++

Comment: Well then the clue is in the <int> which is being assigned the value of a char, but when it is looked at later it is an int hence the number.