# Why ifstream reader read only first 10 bytes of an image file?

Tags: c++, file-io, binaryfiles, ifstream

Here is the code I am trying with:

```
ifstream fileReader("server_data\\test2.jpg", ios::in | ios::binary);
char buffer[RESP_LENGTH];
memset(buffer, '\0', RESP_LENGTH);
if (fileReader.is_open())
{
    fileReader.seekg(0);
    fileReader.read(buffer, RESP_LENGTH);
    cout << buffer<<endl<<"Length: "<<strlen(buffer);
}
fileReader.close();
```

Its simply reading only first few bytes. Its also differing from file to file.

I am suspecting, probably its getting a character which evaluates to NULL and thus my length and string is getting small portion only?

Any Idea what is really happening and how to fix it?

Comment: I cannot tell that the `ifstream` read only few bytes from this. DO NOT use `strlen` to measure length of binary data. [istream::gcount](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/istream/istream/gcount/) is useful to get the length read in this case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is not in the way you are reading in but in the way you are printing out.

If there's a `\0` character this means `end of string`. So string operations (like `strlen` or printing to `cout`) will stop on that character (considering the `string` contained in your `char*` stops here), but it does not mean your `char*` array does not contain more characters....

Instead, you should do that:

```
cout << "Got " << fileReader.gcount() << "characters:";
for ( size_t i = 0; i != fileReader.gcount(); ++i )
    cout << buffer[i];
```

Then, you'll print all bytes you read, ignoring EOS and other special characters.

Note that special characters will not be printed correctly (See [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19562103/uint8-t-cant-be-printed-with-cout)). But I guess your goal is not to print that binary content.

Comment: I would edit this to make it brutally clear to OP that the problem isn't with the reading in, but with the printing out.

Comment: True. Did that. Thanks

Comment: @jpo38 , thanks. Yes, so, I got the point. I am not concerned about printing it, but I am gonna send it over network. So, while copy the stream, I guess I will just need to use 'memcpy' with the buffer array size to copy everything regardless of which characters it contains, right?

Comment: Exactly, use gcount to know how many bytes you have to copy...and then you can accept the answer ;-)

Comment: `ostream::write` could be useful.