# Return unsigned char as a hex value

Tags: c++

I'm aiming to be able to return unsigned char as a hex values, this is so I can pass the value from my client to server side.

How my data is generated before trying to be converted into hex:

```
unsigned char *TestClass::GetKey()
{
    // Generate a key of length 32 bytes
    memset(this->szKey, 0, 32);
    RAND_bytes(this->szKey, 32);

    return this->szKey;
}
```

This what i've currently got so far:

```
TestClass myTestClass;

void CJSCallDoc::OnDocumentComplete(LPCTSTR strURL,LPDISPATCH pDisp)
{
    unsigned char szKey = hex_print(myTestClass.GetKey());
}

unsigned char CJSCallDoc::hex_print(unsigned char* pv)
{
    unsigned char *p = pv;
    if (NULL == pv)
    {
        return NULL;
    }
    else
    {
        char storedString[256];

        size_t len = strlen((const char*)pv);
        size_t i = 0;

        for (; i < len; ++i)
        {
            strcpy_s(storedString, 256, "Test");
            strcat_s(storedString, reinterpret_cast<char*>(*p++));
        }

        return *storedString;
    }
}
```

The problem I'm having is with this line:

```
strcat_s(storedString, reinterpret_cast<char*>(*p++));
```

This line causes my application to crash and this is the following error I get:

> Unhandled exception at 0x01664467 in TestApp.exe: 0xC0000005: Access
>   violation reading location 0x000000FE.

and the error takes me to `tcscat_s.inl`:

```
---> while ((*p++ = *_SRC++) != 0 && --available > 0)
{
}
```

However when I try and do the following it works fine:

```
unsigned char CJSCallDoc::hex_print(unsigned char* pv)
{
    unsigned char *p = pv;
    if (NULL == pv)
    {
        return NULL;
    }
    else
    {
        char storedString[256];

        size_t len = strlen((const char*)pv);
        size_t i = 0;

        for (; i < len; ++i)
        {
            strcpy_s(storedString, 256, "Test");
            strcat_s(storedString, "WORKS");
        }

        return *storedString;
    }
}
```

Could someone explain to me, what I'm doing wrong and give me some advice in the right direction?

Comment: There should be a comment added for reasoning to the downvote. So why the downvote?

Comment: This code is a mess. Why are you doing `reinterpret_cast<char*>(*p++)` ? You are casting a `char` value to a `char*` pointer? No wonder this doesn't work.

Comment: It's not a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), to begin with.

Comment: The undefined behaviour is more than that, Bathseba.  Returning the address of a local (auto) variable causes the caller to exhibit undefined behaviour if it dereferences that pointer, since the variable will no longer exist.   The type or the value stored has nothing to do with it.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ But that's not reason to downvote, i'm still learning. Everyone has had messy code at some point.

Comment: @Bathsheba signed->unsigned should be defined. See conv.integral.2

Comment: @Peter The statement doesn't return an address.

Comment: @ChrisBeckett Also it's completely unclear what you're trying to do. Getting the hex representation of an ASCII character? There are way simpler methods to achieve this.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ Sorry about that, If you re check my question. You can see how my data is generated before trying to change it to hex.

Comment: @ChrisBeckett The simplest way to get a hex representation is to use `ostringstream` and the `hex` manipulator, char must be casted to `int` to do this.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ Could you give any brief example of this?

Comment: Much like done [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19562103/uint8-t-cant-be-printed-with-cout/19562163#19562163) but with an additional [`hex`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/hex) manipulator before outputting.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that you are casting your data to address, in:

```
strcat_s(storedString, reinterpret_cast<char*>(*p++));
```

`*p++` is equal to whatever your string contains - first element is `p` from your example, so you are casting this `p` - decimal value 112, to `char*`. `strcat_s` will try to read string from this location which immediately ends with segfault.