# Why is uint_8t not recommended for representing someones age?

Tags: c++

I am reading some material on C++ and it said that to represent someone's age, int16_t is preferred over uint8_t, even though int16_t has a range of -32,768 to 32,767 and uint8_t has a range of 0 to 255.

A persons age can never be negative, so why is int16_t a better option?

Comment: Provide a link to the material, otherwise the question is difficult to answer without pure opinion.

Comment: Read some more of your book or whatever material. You are asking us "why does this author have this opinion". Nobody knows except for that author

Comment: I know `uint8_t`, but I don't know `uint_8t`. Are you sure you want to use `uint_8t`?

Comment: I've seen people on the committee strongly discourage use of unsigned types for things otherthan bitfields. Wrt ages specifically. the author probably means you should allow `-1` to indicate something like "age not set." but this is just my speculation

Comment: maybe the author is concerned about `cout << age` which may invoke the character-type overload of `<<` on some systems . (But if so, changing the type of `age` to `int16_t` is not a great solution)

Comment: I voted to reopen.  There are sound reasons not to represent a person's age as a `uint8_t`.  And there are also sound reasons not to represent it with a `int16_t`.  But I will stop short of trying to stuff a complete answer into the space of a comment.  I've also upvoted the question.  This is a good beginners' question that sometimes even seasoned C++ programmers get wrong.

Comment: Also voted to reopen.  Classic example for using `int`: `T difference_in_ages = abs(age1 - age2);` works for signed types but not unsigned (as the `age2 > age1` situation yields a "bogus" positive number).  Another: `for (Age i = 10; i >= 0; --i) ...`.  I'm not arguing either way, but saying there are factual pros/cons to be listed, and "primarily opinion-based" is not a good reason for closing the Q.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There may be a couple of reasons for this choice.

For example, if your program compares birth date to current date you will eventually run into cases where the `uint8_t` will overflow if your program is in use long enough.

Or if the person is dead, or has an invalid age you may wish to set a negative number as a form of error, `-1` for not set, `-2` for dead, `-3` for out of range, etc.

On some platforms `cout` will treat `uint8_t` as a `char` when printing, causing confusing output to those who do not expect it. ( @M.M pointed this out, [More Info](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19562103/uint8-t-cant-be-printed-with-cout) )

This approach also allows you more flexibility with the allowance of negative numbers / larger values. Basically in the general case memory is quite cheep, specially when dealing with 8 bits.
It's better to write code that has less chance of overflowing and is more flexable than to worry about packing more data into a smaller space.

Comment: re. the first para, that would only occur if they also used `uint8_t` for storing date ranges, and there's no suggestion of that in the OP. (Although it is not a very clear post)

Comment: @M.M I was more thinking, `age = date1 - date2` where `age` is the `uint8_t`, though... Maybe I wasn't clear enough on that point?

Answer (score 0):

There shouldn't be any reason to use an int_16 over a uint_8t unless your chipset is a 16 bit chip, where 16 bit operations would run more efficiently than 8 bit ones, although now days most people would never use a 16 bit chip, even in embedded systems programming.

Comment: I've removed the first sentence since it seems irrelevant to your actual answer - but I'm just a person like you, so if you disagree, you can put it back.