# std::cout deal with uint8_t as a character

Tags: c++, c++11, language-lawyer, cout, fixed-size-types

If I run this code:

```
std::cout << static_cast<uint8_t>(65);
```

It will output:

> A

Which is the ASCII equivalent of the number 65.
This is because `uint8_t` is simply defined as:

```
typedef unsigned char uint8_t;
```

- Is this behavior a standard?
- Should not be a better way to define `uint8_t` that guaranteed to be dealt with as a number not a character?

I can not understand the logic that if I want to print the value of a `uint8_t` variable, it will be printed as a character.

P.S. I am using MSVS 2013.

Comment: Yes it's standards behavior. If you want to use a `uint8_t` as a small unsigned integer you need to cast it before outputting it. Like e.g. `static_cast<uint32_t>(some_uint8_t_variable)`

Comment: Thanks.. It is not duplicated exactly.. I know why this behaviour is exist. My main two questions were: if this is a standard behaviour and why there is no better way to represent uint8_t as non character type.

Comment: @HumamHelfawi What type could it be?  Only `char` is guaranteed to have a `sizeof()` of 1.

Comment: @NathanOliver Yes that is exactly my question. Why it could not be a primitive type that has also a size of 1 with another name.

Comment: @HumamHelfawi - there is no primitive type that has a size of 1 and is not a variant of `char`. Yes, C++ could have added a new type, but that would conflict with C, which is where these typedefs originated.

Comment: `std::cout << +static_cast<uint8_t>(65);` will do what you want.

Comment: As Pete said there is no other type.  `bool` and everything else has an implementation defined size.  The only type the exist with a know size of 1 is the char variants.

Comment: @PeteBecker thanks.. is + a unary operator that return some int? because I could not leverage into its declaration within MSVS IDE. It said "there is no overload for + operator"

Comment: `+` is a unary operator that acts a lot like the unary `-`, except that it doesn't negate the value. It's generally viewed as pointless, but it **is** useful here, because, as an arithmetic operator, the compiler promotes its argument to `int`. So `+x` is equivalent to `(int)x`.

Comment: @NathanOliver I see. However, as Pete said, it seems a compatibility problem with C. I see that there is no choice rather than char or a totally new type.

Comment: @HumamHelfawi it would be a compiler bug if `+static_cast<uint8_t>(65)` failed on your compiler

Comment: @M.M No it did not.. I just could not see its implementation or declaration (IDE problem not compiler problem)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [uint8\_t can't be printed with cout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19562103/uint8-t-cant-be-printed-with-cout)

Comment: FWIW, it isn't guaranteed at all that you can even print the `uint[_fast|_least]N_t` types this way.  You have to first cast to `unsigned long long`, for instance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Is this behavior a standard

The behavior is standard in that if `uint8_t` is a typedef of `unsigned char` then it will always print a character as `std::ostream` has an overload for `unsigned char` and prints out the contents of the variable as a character.

> Should not be a better way to define `uint8_t` that guaranteed to be dealt with as a number not a character?

In order to do this the C++ committee would have had to introduce a new fundamental type.  Currently the only types that has a `sizeof()` that is equal to 1 is `char`, `signed char`, and `unsigned char`.  It is possible they could use a `bool` but `bool` does not have to have a size of 1 and then you are still in the same boat since

```
int main()
{
    bool foo = 42;
    std::cout << foo << '\n';
}
```

will print `1`, not `42` as any non zero is true and true is printed as `1` but default.

I'm not saying it can't be done but it is a lot of work for something that can be handled with a [cast or a function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19562103/uint8-t-cant-be-printed-with-cout)

---

C++17 introduces [`std::byte`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/byte) which is defined as `enum class byte : unsigned char {};`.  So it will be one byte wide but it is not a character type.  Unfortunately, since it is an `enum class` it comes with it's own limitations.  The bit-wise operators have been defined for it but there is no built in stream operators for it so you would need to define your own to input and output it.   That means you are still converting it but at least you wont conflict with the built in operators for `unsigned char`.  That gives you something like

```
std::ostream& operator <<(std::ostream& os, std::byte b)
{
    return os << std::to_integer<unsigned int>(b);
}

std::istream& operator <<(std::istream& is, std::byte& b)
{
    unsigned int temp;
    is >> temp;
    b = std::byte{b};
    return is;
}

int main()
{
    std::byte foo{10};
    std::cout << foo;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

It's indirectly standard behavior, because `ostream` has an overload for `unsigned char` and `unsigned char` is a typedef for same type `uint8_t` in your system.

§27.7.3.1 [output.streams.ostream] gives:

```
template<class traits>
basic_ostream<char,traits>& operator<<(basic_ostream<char,traits>&, unsigned char);
```

I couldn't find anywhere in the standard that explicitly stated that `uint8_t` and `unsigned char` *had* to be the same, though. It's just that it's reasonable that they both occupy 1 byte in nearly all implementations.

```
 std::cout << std::boolalpha << std::is_same<uint8_t, unsigned char>::value << std::endl; // prints true
```

To get the value to print as an integer, you need a type that is not `unsigned char` (or one of the other character overloads). Probably a simple cast to `uint16_t` is adequate, because the standard doesn't list an overload for it:

```
uint8_t a = 65;
std::cout << static_cast<uint16_t>(a) << std::endl; // prints 65
```

[Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/f6ab6aba37263360)

Comment: They don't have to be the same; `uint8_t` could be an extended integer type.

Comment: You wont find anything that actually spells out what the underlying type of `uint8_t` has to be as `uint8_t` might not even exist.

Comment: `uint16_t` might have the same problem , on a system with 16-bit `char`.  (Those are rare though)

Comment: @M.M: I was trying to convey that they didn't have to be the same, it's just that they are and OP (and everyone else who asks about printing `uint8_t`) is just unlucky that their implementation chose `unsigned char` to be a typedef for it, and it probably won't change soon, because it's a reasonable implementation.

Answer (score 3):

Posting an answer as there is some misinformation in comments.

The `uint8_t` may or may not be a typedef for `char` or `unsigned char`. It is also possible for it to be an extended integer type (and so, not a character type).

Compilers may offer other integer types besides the minimum set required by the standard (`short`, `int`, `long`, etc).  For example some compilers offer a 128-bit integer type.

This would not "conflict with C" either, since C and C++ both allow for extended integer types.

So, your code has to allow for both possibilities. The suggestion in comments of using unary `+` would work.

Personally I think it would make more sense if the standard required `uint8_t` to *not* be a character type, as the behaviour you have noticed is unintuitive.

Comment: Yes exactly that what I was thinking of. Thanks

Comment: If the standard mandates that it should not be a character type what type should be used?

Comment: @NathanOliver an 8-bit integer type that is not a character type