# What is the purpose of a unary "+" before a call to std::numeric_limits<unsigned char> members?

Tags: c++, char, unary-operator

I saw [this example in cppreference's documentation for `std::numeric_limits`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/numeric_limits)

```
#include <limits>
#include <iostream>

int main() 
{
    std::cout << "type\tlowest()\tmin()\t\tmax()\n\n";

    std::cout << "uchar\t"
              << +std::numeric_limits<unsigned char>::lowest() << '\t' << '\t'
              << +std::numeric_limits<unsigned char>::min() << '\t' << '\t'
              << +std::numeric_limits<unsigned char>::max() << '\n';
    std::cout << "int\t"
              << std::numeric_limits<int>::lowest() << '\t'
              << std::numeric_limits<int>::min() << '\t'
              << std::numeric_limits<int>::max() << '\n';
    std::cout << "float\t"
              << std::numeric_limits<float>::lowest() << '\t'
              << std::numeric_limits<float>::min() << '\t'
              << std::numeric_limits<float>::max() << '\n';
    std::cout << "double\t"
              << std::numeric_limits<double>::lowest() << '\t'
              << std::numeric_limits<double>::min() << '\t'
              << std::numeric_limits<double>::max() << '\n';
}
```

I don't understand the "+" operator in

```
<< +std::numeric_limits<unsigned char>::lowest()
```

I have tested it, replaced it with "-", and that also worked.
What is the use of such a "+" operator?

Comment: Try it. What do you get if you leave out the `+`?

Comment: This question would not *need* to be asker if the writer of the code cares to explain what it means or use an explicit cast instead...

Comment: if you replace with `-` then the outputs won't be the correct values for the limits

Comment: For the record, if you want to Google this kind of thing in yourself, this is called the "unary plus" operator -- it's unary because it takes a single value (in this case, the thing right after it), and "plus" is the Google-friendly way to say `+`. In this case, your query would probably be "c++ unary plus". It's... not exactly intuitive, and you still have to learn to read the documentation that you'll find, but IMO it's a useful skill to cultivate.

Answer (score 139, accepted):

The output operator `<<` when being passed a `char` (signed or unsigned) will write it as a *character*.

Those function will return values of type `unsigned char`. And as noted above that will print the characters those values represent in the current encoding, not their integer values.

The `+` operator converts the `unsigned char` returned by those functions to an `int` through [*integer promotion*](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/conversion#Integer_promotions). Which means the integer values will be printed instead.

An expression like `+std::numeric_limits<unsigned char>::lowest()` is essentially equal to `static_cast<int>(std::numeric_limits<unsigned char>::lowest())`.

Answer (score 37):

`+` is there to turn the `unsigned char` into an `int`. The `+` operator is value preserving, but it has the effect of inducing integral promotion on its operand. It's to make sure you see a numerical value instead of some (semi-)random character that `operator <<` would print when given a character type.

Answer (score 20):

Just to add a reference to the answers already given. From the CPP standard working draft [N4713](https://wg21.link/n4713):

> **8.5.2.1 Unary operators**
>   ...
>
> > 7. The operand of the unary + operator shall have arithmetic, unscoped enumeration, or pointer type and the result is the value of the argument. **Integral promotion is performed on integral or enumeration operands.** The type of the result is the type of the promoted operand.

And `char`, `short`, `int`, and `long` are integral types.

Answer (score 12):

Without `+` the result will be different. The following snippet outputs `a 97` instead of `a a`

```
char ch = 'a';
std::cout << ch << ' ' << +ch << '\n';
```

The reason is because **different overloads prints different types of data**.
There's no `basic_ostream& operator<<( char value );` overload for [`std::basic_ostream`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ostream/operator_ltlt) and it's explained at the end of the page

> Character and character string arguments (e.g., of type `char` or `const char*`) are handled by the [non-member overloads](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ostream/operator_ltlt2) of `operator<<`. Attempting to output a character using the member function call syntax (e.g., `std::cout.operator<<('c');`) **will call one of overloads (2-4) and output the numerical value**. Attempting to output a character string using the member function call syntax will call overload (7) and print the pointer value instead.

The [non-member overload](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ostream/operator_ltlt2) that will be called when you pass a `char` variable is

```
template< class CharT, class Traits> basic_ostream<CharT,Traits>& operator<<(
    basic_ostream<CharT,Traits>& os, char ch );
```

which prints out the character at the codepoint `ch`

So basically if you pass `char`, `signed char` or `unsigned char` directly to the stream it'll print the character out. If you try removing the `+` on the above lines you'll see that it prints some "strange" or non-visible characters which is not what one would expect

If you want their numerical values instead you must call the overload for `short`, `int`, `long` or `long long`. The easiest way to do this is promoting from `char` to `int` with unary plus `+`. That's one of the [rare useful applications](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14365849/995714) of the [unary plus operator](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6637005/995714). An explicit cast to `int` will also work

There are many people who faced that problem on SO like

- [cout not printing unsigned char](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15585267/995714)
- [std::cout deal with uint8_t as a character](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39145753/995714)
- [uint8_t can't be printed with cout](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19562103/995714)

Comment: Did you mean unary _plus_, not minus?