# C++ Why is that my output for str [i] is empty?

Tags: c++

Below are my codes:

```
    char str [80];
    int n;

     n = MAX + ( rand () % 1000 + 1);
     cout << "number: " << n << endl;

     constructArray(str, n);



    void constructArray (char str [], int n)
    {
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        while (n > 0)
        {
           // get last pair of digits
           str [i] = n%10;

            n/= 10;
        }
      cout << str[i] << endl;
    }
    }
```

I can't figure out why my compiler doesnt output any values. 
It works if I didnt implement array.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: The right tool to solve such problems is your debugger. You should step through your code line-by-line *before* asking on Stack Overflow. For more help, please read [How to debug small programs (by Eric Lippert)](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/). At a minimum, you should \[edit] your question to include a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example that reproduces your problem, along with the observations you made in the debugger.

Comment: Are you running into [this issue](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19562103/uint8-t-cant-be-printed-with-cout/19562163#19562163) finally?

Comment: This question does not show any research effort; It is unclear or not useful

Answer (score 0):

In the first iteration of your `for` loop, when `while` is executed for the first time (`i=0`), `n` will be reduced to 0. Thus your for loop will execute only once. This will lead to only `str[0]` being set. Others already pointed out that char cant store large numbers, but this is differnt problem.

Answer (score 0):

There are few problems with you code.

- You are storing `integer` in `char` type array.
- `for` loop will only be executed only once because `while` loop make `n = 0`.

hence only `str[0]` will be assigned.

Answer (score 0):

In the `while` loop,the `n` is still divided by 10 until `n` is reduced to 0. Then the `for` loop will finished. So only output `str[0]`.