# Storing value of string into char array

Tags: c++, arrays, string, uint8t

I am attempting to create a Big Integer class but have run into an issue. I have an overloaded constructor that's giving me some issues. It is supposed to take in a string and convert that string into a `std::uint8_t*` called `m_number`, keep track of the number of digits, and keep track of space allocated for each `std::uint8_t*`. The numbers are loaded in backwards, with the least significant digit being `m_number[0]`. The issue I'm having is with storing '0' into the array. The function works fine for any other value, but if a string has a '0' in it, the function stops storing values into the `std::uint_8*`.
Here is my class definition:

```
      class BigInteger
    {
    public:
        BigInteger add(const BigInteger& rhs);
        BigInteger multiply(const BigInteger& rhs);
        void display();
        BigInteger();
        BigInteger(const BigInteger& rOther);
        BigInteger(int);
        BigInteger(std::string);
        BigInteger& operator=(const BigInteger & rhs);

    private:
        std::uint8_t* m_number;
        unsigned int m_sizeReserved;
        unsigned int m_digitCount;
}
```

Here's my overloaded constructor:

```
BigInteger::BigInteger(std::string str) {
    m_digitCount = str.length();
    m_sizeReserved = m_digitCount;
    m_number = new std::uint8_t[m_sizeReserved];
    std::uint8_t* aArray = new std::uint8_t[m_sizeReserved];
    int j = str.length()-1;
    for(int i=0; i < m_digitCount; i++, j--) {
            aArray[i] = str[j]-'0';
    }
    for(int i=0; i < m_digitCount; i++) {
        m_number[i] = aArray[i];
    }
    delete[] aArray;

}
```

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]. Btw, you have two `new` but only one `delete` smells like memory leak

Comment: "the function stops storing values" are you sure? Seems to me like the issue would arise when reading the string not storing it. You could just use a `std::vector` instead to hold the size instead of reading to nul and assuming that will terminate at the size of your string.

Comment: Make life simpler, use `std::vector`.

Comment: The general idea seems sound. http://ideone.com/UssjvB.

Comment: I guess you could also wait until you're reading the string before bothering to convert, i.e. `aArray[i] = str[j]-'0';` -> `aArray[i] = str[j];` & then something like `for( int i = 0; m_number[i] != 0; ++i ) std::cout << m_number[i]-'0';`

Comment: @George Yes you're correct. The issue occurs while setting aArray to str. Whenever str == '0', the array stops storing values and won't store any subsequent values. I tried your suggestion which did allow me to store the string in the array, but once it tries to store it into m_number it then stops at the '0' value

Comment: How are you creating this string str?

Comment: @CaydenAnderson -- This is a simple one-liner if you used `std::vector` for m_number, as [seen here](http://ideone.com/ku72VO).  All of this dynamic allocation of temporary arrays is not necessary.

Comment: @Florianp.i. I'm just calling the constructor such as 'BigInteger("1238970")'. While loading this value in, the value of m_number should be 0798321 but would come out empty since the first value is a zero

Comment: @CaydenAnderson -- It's even a one-liner if you don't use `std::vector` and used `new[]`.  [See here](http://ideone.com/SlB7s0).

Comment: @Paul this seems like a much easier work around, but my complier is still stopping once the value is '0' in the string using this method. Could this possibly just be an error with Xcode?

Comment: @CaydenAnderson [Cannot duplicate](http://ideone.com/VxkDtE)

Answer (score 0):

**The problem is that uint8_t is treated like unsigned char.**

So if you pass it through cout, it will interpret your 0 as index for ASCII, which is '\0' and stop.
So you have to ensure cout doesn't interpret your integer information as character information.

See this for solutions and further information: 
[uint8_t can't be printed with cout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19562103/uint8-t-cant-be-printed-with-cout)

Comment: The issue doesn't arise from std::cout as I never actually output the value, it's a problem in storing the value

Comment: If you don`t use any output, how do you know that there is a problem? At which line of code can you detect its not storing a value?