# Print `uint8_t` value to `std::cout` using the `<<` operator

Tags: c++

As c++ newbie, I can't fully understand why the following code doesn't work (by "doesn't work" I mean, I don't see the output 255 but instead a "broken" character):

```
uint8_t num = 0xff;
std::cout << num << std::endl;
```

I guess, `num` is treated here somehow like a (non printable) character.

But I've found a code sample that solves my problem:

```
uint8_t num = 0xff;
std::cout << +num << std::endl;
```

At the moment, I have no idea what the `+` operator does in this case, and I really don't know how to google this question...

I would really appreciate it if someone could point me to right direction.
Many thanks in advance!

Edit:

The first part of my question is duplicate of:

[uint8_t can't be printed with cout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19562103/uint8-t-cant-be-printed-with-cout)

The answer to second part of my question (**why** the unary `+` operator helps in this case) can also be found there if you read through all answers and comments. The keyword is **integer promotion**

Comment: The + operator promotes it to an integer, which is then printed as a number.

Comment: Edit your question to get rid of any sense of the duplicate material. Then it may be answered.

Comment: Oh, and don't place "EDIT" in all caps. The post should be readable and self contained, without any ad-hoc versioning. The site will keep up of the edit history just fine on its own.

Comment: Sry for that. Actually after reading through all the answers https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19562103/uint8-t-cant-be-printed-with-cout answered all my questions. Please close the question.

Comment: @erenon: thank you too, you've also answered the second part of my question correctly