# boost::any with structs and unsigned ints

Tags: c++, c++11, boost, unsigned-integer, boost-any

There are several parts to my question. I have been researching on how/when to use `boost::any`.  I was wondering if it is possible to assign a `struct` to a `boost::any` variable.

**Example:**

```
struct S {
   int x;
};

S s;
s.x = 5;

boost::any var = s;
```

It would seem to me that this is possible but it leads me to my next question.  If this is a valid assignment, then how would I access the data member `x`?  `var` is not a `struct` type since it is `boost::any`.

My next question is not dependent on whether the data member can be accessed or not.  The question then is, what if variable `a` is of type `uint8_t`.

**Example:** *Edit: as pointed out in the comments, the code below does support uint8_t but it is not printed. See* [uint8_t can't be printed with cout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19562103/uint8-t-cant-be-printed-with-cout).

```
uint8_t a = 10;

boost::any b = a;

std::cout << boost::any_cast<uint8_t>(b);
```

I found that it is possible to use `boost::any_cast` but have not found that it supports unsigned types.  When I tried using `boost::any_cast<uint8_t>()` it did not print, but did not throw an error.  Is it possible to get the value of a type like `uint8_t` using `boost`?  If so how?

I will continue reading more documentation of [boost::any](https://theboostcpplibraries.com/boost.any) but if anyone has insight, details, or notes on these questions or the subject, please post as I would love to learn more about how this works.  Thanks!

Comment: Best way to be sure is to try it. I don't see any issue with uint8_t except pre-c++11 where it could be aliased to char. The principle of any is type erasure. google it

Comment: As described in the documentation you linked to, the conversion is via `any_cast`, not `cast_any`. If that is a typo in your question, please fix it. If that's a typo in your code, then maybe that's what one of your problems is.

Comment: @JaMiT yes that is a typo, thank you.

Comment: casting to `uint8_t` with `any_cast` should work. You may be having [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19562103/uint8-t-cant-be-printed-with-cout) problem

Comment: @vu1p3n0x I think you are correct.  Since I couldn't see the value, I used `sizeof` on `any_cast` and saw that it was 1.  So I think the value is there.. thanks for input

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I was wondering if it is possible to assign a struct to a `boost::any` variable

It is.

> How would I access the data member `x`?

You would access with `any_cast<S>(var).x`. Continuing your example:

```
int& the_x_member = any_cast<S>(var).x;
std::cout << "s.x is " << the_x_member << "\n";
```

> What if variable `a` is of type `uint8_t`?

It's perfectly possible to assign an unsigned integer type to a `boost::any` (or `std::any`, which does the same thing but with somewhat different syntax).

> When I tried using `boost::any_cast<uint8_t>()` it did not print, but did not throw an error.

Wouldn't that "print" a `\0` character? So it would look like nothing was printed.

> Is it possible to get the value of a type like `uint8_t` using Boost? If so how?

Just like you'd expect:

```
uint8_t u = 234;
boost::any ba = u;
std::cout << "u is " << (int) boost::any_cast<uint8_t>(ba) << '\n';
```

This [does indeed work](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/b91237848a39abae).

Comment: Thanks so much for the insight, extremely helpful.  I realize my second example is misleading using `x` again and it makes it seem that I did in fact think it was a data member still.  I will edit that so it is more clear for future readers.  Much appreciated!