# Assigning a static_cast<int>(-15) to a static const char type variable

Tags: c++

Hello it may be some silly question, but this is bugging me since few days.

I have bellow line of code:

```
static const char x1 = static_cast<int>(-15);
cout<<x1;

static const char x2= 16;
cout<< "hello "<< x2<<'\n';
```

The output is None I mean nothing is getting printed in console. But when I did the comparison like `if(kill == -15)` its evaluated as True. So may I know why I can not see any output in console when I am printing.

Comment: What do you get when you do: `cout << '(' << x1 << ')';`

Comment: What would you expect should be printed? Take a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19562103/uint8-t-cant-be-printed-with-cout/19562163#19562163) please.

Comment: You have cast at wrong place. It should be `cout<<static_cast<int>(x1);` instead.

Comment: @AtesGoral I am getting a ? with background, when I used parenthesis but invisible symbol without parenthesis why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are printing a `char`, it is taken as an ASCII value. I.e., `std::cout << char{66};` would print `B`.

If you want to print your char as a number, simply prepend `+`.

Comment: The C++ standard does not guarantee that it will use ASCII. It could be ASCII (and very often is) but it is not guaranteed.

Comment: @mrks What is the magic behind + as a prefix, please explain.

Comment: @PrashantPathak I'd go doe something more explicit and obvious like a cast, but `char` is an integer type with some special handling when displayed . When you perform arithmetic on a `char` it is promoted to an `int` and is printed out as an `int`. Some examples: https://ideone.com/RBInD8