# Poco::Logger print int8_t value

Tags: c++, format, printf, poco

I am trying to print int8_t value with [Poco::Logger](https://pocoproject.org/docs/Poco.html#13076) in this way:

```
using myint8_t = signed char;
myint8_t var;
var = 10;
logger().information("%c", var);
logger().information("%d", var);
logger().information("%i", var);
```

But as output have error which tells me that argument does not match the format specifier:

```
2018-10-02 00:12:40.627 [Information] [ERRFMT]
2018-10-02 00:12:40.627 [Information] [ERRFMT]
2018-10-02 00:12:40.627 [Information] [ERRFMT]
```

Where is my mistake and how to print signed char value with [Poco::Logger](https://pocoproject.org/docs/Poco.html#13076)?
Thanks.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19562103/uint8-t-cant-be-printed-with-cout/19562163#19562163

Comment: Totally unrelated: the `_t` suffix is reserved by the POSIX standard. Use with caution on POSIX compliant systems.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ I my case I use `signed char`. In example above `unsigned char` is used.

Comment: Try to use `logger().information("%?i", var);`

Comment: It works with `%?i` but what modifiers `?` means? According to the documentation it is: `? argument is any signed or unsigned int, short, long, or 64-bit integer (d, i, o, x, X).` Could you please explain me more deeper.

Comment: @definename The related point is the cast, if you want to output a number.

Comment: Poco uses a type safe format class but allows for any int cast via the `?` modifier.

Comment: See [format](https://pocoproject.org/docs/Poco.html#14526)