# ASCII to dec stored in string

Tags: c++

The string `str_hex` contains the hex-values for the letters A-J, which corresponds to the decimal values 65-74.  I'm trying to cast each hex-value to its decimal value [following this example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19562103/uint8-t-cant-be-printed-with-cout).  It works nice for the `std::cout` case inside the for-loop, but the output-`std::string` still has the ascii-values.  Why does this not work or is there a nicer/more proper way to build my output string?

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <stdint.h>

int main()
{

    std::string str_hex("\x41\x42\x43\x44\x45\x46\x47\x48\x49\x4a\x4b", 10);
    std::string str_output = "";

    for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i)
    {
        uint8_t tmp = str_hex[i];
        str_output.append(1, (unsigned)tmp);
        std::cout << "cout+for: " << (unsigned)tmp << std::endl;
        if(i<9)
            str_output.append(1, '-');
    }
    std::cout << std::endl << "cout+str_append: " << str_output  << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Compiling and running the program gives the following output:

```
cout+for: 65
cout+for: 66
cout+for: 67
...

cout+str_append: A-B-C-D-E-F-G-H-I-J
```

The desired output is:

```
cout+str_append: 65-66-67-68-...
```

Comment: Advice -- [you could have whittled this down to a tiny program](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/18359f74b56f8d34), attempting to create a string from a number.  Possibly you could have figured this out yourself by doing as such.  The loop, hyphen character, hex string, etc. were unnecessary in creating a [mcve].

Comment: Thank you for your comment, I realize that my (already stripped down) example could be made much more focused.  I take that into account if a post a new question :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The method `string::append` accepts, among the various overload, a `size_t` and a `char`, see [reference](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/append/).

> string& append (size_t n, char c);

Therefore, in your code line

```
str_output.append(1, (unsigned)tmp);
```

you are implicitly converting the unsigned `tmp` to a char, i.e., to a single letter. To obtain the output you want, you have to convert `tmp` to a string containing the number, and then append it to `str_output`. You can do that by using

```
str_output+=std::to_string(tmp);
```

instead of `str_output.append(1, (unsigned)tmp);`.

Answer (score 0):

You have to change your string `append` to for the change from a number to its "string":

```
str_output.append(std::to_string(tmp));
```

It's not one character that you want to add, but a string representing the number.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.  I'm new to C++, so I cannot tell which of yours and francescos answer is the "proper" one.  However my python-background favors the `str += "abc"` notation.

Comment: Both are the same, both append the string after your previous strings.