# String to ascii hex/int value

Tags: c++

I am trying to convert a string to a vector of ASCII value uint8_t

For example, if I have a string that is `"500"` I would want a vector that is `{53, 48, 48}` where these values are hex 0x35, 0x30, 0x30. This is what I am currently doing and it is not working

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
int main() {
    std::string number = "500";
    std::vector<std::uint8_t> bytes;
    for (auto& c : number)
        bytes.push_back(static_cast<std::uint8_t>(c));

    for (auto& c : bytes)
        std::cout << c << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

But I just get 5, 0, 0 as output where I was expecting 53, 48, 48

Comment: You haven't written any code that would convert anything to a displayable hex representation. If that's what you want, which isn't clear.

Comment: @NeilButterworth I was just hoping to get the integer value, I will edit the question.

Answer (score 1):

`std::cout << c << std::endl;` is writing `std::uint8_t` as a character (see [this question for details](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19562103/4899740)).
You have to cast it to an integer to actually get the result you want.

For example ([wandbox link](https://wandbox.org/permlink/CfJ00wbHkay3w8WY)):

```
std::cout << static_cast<int>(c) << std::endl;
```