# How do I use an uint8_t with I/O streams while avoiding the char behavior?

Tags: c++, io, integer, iostream

Consider this simple C++ program:

```
#include <cstdint>
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    uint8_t var;
    std::cin >> var;
    std::cout << "var = " << var << '\n';
    if (var == 1) {
        std::cout << "var is 1\n";
    } else {
        std::cout << "var is not 1\n";
    }
}
```

Running it shows some surprising behavior. When the input is `1`, [the output is](https://tio.run/##hY3BCoMwEETv@YrBHrSHHnIrNuZLhBJiWhZ0FRO9FL89jUppKYXuZYc3M7t2GE53a2M8ENt2ahyU9aEhDlq8EfU@jM50WojkoDPExREPgTRTIudrwGzGywZSvSwtMbT@hv0UoBSyhFEhW/Uq08przvck3VBsfgX5@vH7AnnImrO9tsC13v3Lcx8@O2IRMcon)

```
var = 1
var is not 1
```

which is clearly absurd! After quite a few varied tests, I realized what is happening—[it's reading and writing a `char`!](https://tio.run/##hY3BCsIwEETv@YqhHloPHnqTmgY/pCAhjbLQbkuTeJF@e0xbRBHBvezwZmbXjOPhZkyMO2LThdZCGudbYq/EG9Hg/GR1r4RIDnpNXOzxEEgTEjlePO56Oq0g1avKEEOpbzgEDymRJYwa2aIXmVbecL4l6Ypi9WuUrx@/L5BD2XC21WbYztl/eR78Z0fMIsbzEw) Still, it's not the behavior I want—I used `uint8_t` because I want the `int`eger behavior. *How can I make `uint8_t` behave like the other integer types when doing stream I/O?* Alternatively, *what one-byte type should I use instead*?

Comment: If you have C++17, switch to using `std::byte`.  Then you can overload the input and output operators to "do the right thing"

Comment: `uint8_t` gets inputted as a char, so its value is 31, not 1.

Comment: @lakeweb read the question. I already know that. I'm not asking what's happening, but how to get more reasonable behavior.

Comment: You can't. You have to read an `unsigned int` and then convert it to `uint8_t`.

Comment: @NathanOliver Thanks! I mostly use C++ for small, one-off programs, so this would be somewhat overkill. I'll probably still switch to `std::byte` to avoid getting bitten by this in the future. Though, is there anything built-in that's really an integer?

Comment: @NieDzejkob Unfortunately not.  The smallest "int type" is `short int`.  Anything smaller is typically `bool` or `char`, with `bool` not really being suitable.

Comment: The question is the answer. The std::stream will treat a byte as a char. As said in the answers, tell the std::stream to treat it otherwise. And it _one-off_ stuff, I would just use the C cast.

Comment: There's [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21389821/7359094) to a similar question, but about `std::cout`.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux Oh durp.  Somehow I missed the namespace.

Answer (score 3):

You need to cast to `int`:

```
std::cout << "var = " << static_cast<int>(var) << '\n';
```

or shorter (C-style):

```
std::cout << "var = " << (int)var << '\n';   //or:
std::cout << "var = " << int(var) << '\n';   //constructor-like
```

or even shorter (promoting to `int` with an arithmetic operator):

```
std::cout << "var = " << +var << '\n';
```

Comment: While the last one is shorter, I would argue that it's clever/surprising so I would personally advise against it.

Answer (score 3):

> How can I make uint8_t behave like the other integer types when doing stream I/O?

<strike>You can't.</strike> [Apparently](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21389821/7359094) you can.

If `std::uint8_t` is an alias of `unsigned char`, as it usually (maybe always) is, then it is a character type, and the standard streams treat it as a character type.

You can convert it to a non-character integer type before inserting to a stream:

```
 std::cout << "var = " << static_cast<unsigned>(var) << '\n';
```

Or with an intermediary variable:

```
unsigned temp = var;
std::cout << "var = " << temp << '\n';
```

Stream extraction works only with the intermediary variable approach:

```
unsigned temp;
std::cin >> temp;
var = temp;
```

---

On a related note, if you wish to output the address of a variable, then `std::cout << &var;` won't work, because it will be treated as a null terminated string... which it isn't and thus results in undefined behaviour. To achieve that, you can use `std::cout << static_cast<void*>(&var);`.

Comment: Fair enough. Is there an equivalent for `cin`?

Comment: `unsigned temp = var;` this is an implicit conversion to `int` thus idiomatically uglier. Giving that syntactically also bulkier it is pointless if compared to a direct cast.