# Is 'std::ios::sync_with_stdio(true);' before 'scanf()' and 'std::ios::sync_with_stdio(false);' after, a good practice?

Tags: c++, performance, iostream, stdio

I haven't found yet an alternative to the `scanf` function to store an input number (as an unsigned tiny integer, not really as char) into an unsigned char variable, but, reading around Internet (and A LOT on SO),

I've discovered that if I write `std::ios::sync_with_stdio(false);` in my C++ code that doesn't use either `printf` or `scanf` (but only std::cin and std::cout), the code is faster.

And the problem is that: I need `scanf`.

But then I thought if I write a sort of `sync_with_stdio` guard just before and after my very very rare `scanf` call, would it work?

It works but what about the speed? I don't know, maybe it has also got worse. I'm still a newbie, and I still don't know how to properly profile the performance of the code.

Would it be a good idea?

Code:

```
#include <iostream>
using std::cin; using std::cout;
int main()
{
    unsigned char little_number_from_0_to_255 = 0;
    cout << "How old are you (for example)? _";

    
    std::ios::sync_with_stdio(true);

    scanf("%hhu", &little_number_from_0_to_255);

    std::ios::sync_with_stdio(false);


    cout << "You are " << +little_number_from_0_to_255
        << " year/s old.";
}
```

Comment: Please don't spam that tags, the question has nothing to do with C.

Comment: Why do you think you need to use `scanf()`?  The C++ iostream system is supposed to be a replacement for C's standard I/O.

Comment: q.v. https://stackoverflow.com/a/58455871/4641116

Comment: Please read [ask] and https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask. We need *objective* criteria in order to have an answerable question. If you are concerned about performance, best to test it yourself first.

Answer (score 0):

First, you don't need scanf and I personally feel it's a mistake to use old-school C routines for reading input. What I would do is use `getline()` and parse it myself with `std::stoi()`'. That gives you greater capability for error detection and reporting.

Next, I also consider it a mistake to use `unsigned char` because you want an integer value. Space is just not that short, and it's misleading. For learning to code, yeah, fine, do what you want. But if you become a professional, it's confusing. You can write that code, but someone else is going to have to maintain it. Just use an int.

Comment: Please read [answer]. While your opinions are entirely reasonable, they are still opinions - and we deal in the objective here. The question solicits opinions such as this - which is exactly why, as written, it should be closed and not answered (see also https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask).

Comment: We do not remotely "deal in the objective" here.  That is a conceit held by those who think that their opinions are objective.  But it's pretty to think so.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel I look forward to your better answer, then.

Comment: "I look forward to your better answer, then." What part of "as written, [the question] should be closed and not answered" was unclear?