# is casting float to unsigned char a valid conversion?

Tags: c++, casting, floating-point, char

Can someone please explain how `float` to `uint32_t` casting works? Is it a valid conversion?

The output of the first line in the below code make sense to me, but the rest are I can't figure out myself.

```
cout<<uint8_t(256+33)<<'\n';
cout<<uint8_t(float(256+33))<<'\n';
cout<<int(uint8_t(float(256+33)))<<'\n';
cout<<int(uint8_t(float(256+3)))<<'\n';
cout<<int(uint8_t(float(256+20)))<<'\n';
```

output

```
!
�
255
255
255
```

`uint8_t(256+33)` is int to unsigned char, and it gives `!`, which is what I expect. However, `float` to `uint8_t` does not work at all. And when I try to cast the output to int, it gives me constant number `255`.

I've a `vector<float>` and want to convert it into `vector<uint8_t>`, which will to passed into a function. What it a valid way to convert `float` to `uint8_t`? Will `static_cast<uint8_t>` will work? Should I first convert `float` to `int` and then `int` to `uint8_t`?

Comment: You are not casting, you are initializing values.

Comment: it has nothing to with the cast. It's just how `std::cout` works with `char`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [uint8\_t can't be printed with cout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19562103/uint8-t-cant-be-printed-with-cout)

Comment: @phuclv Nope. I've updated my question. I am trying to convert a vector of `float` to `uint8_t`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

They are not valid, but are undefined.

In C++17:

4.10 Floating-integral conversions [conv.fpint]

> A prvalue of a floating-point type can be converted to a prvalue of an integer type. The conversion truncates; that is, the fractional part is discarded. The behavior is undefined if the truncated value cannot be represented in the destination type.

The `int` conversion is well-defined, which you can't assume just because the result makes sense to you:

4.8 Integral conversions [conv.integral], item 2

> If the destination type is unsigned, the resulting value is the least unsigned integer congruent to the source integer (modulo 2<sup>n</sup> where n is the number of bits used to represent the unsigned type).

Comment: To complete: the first one instead is well defined because a conversion from a signed integral type to an unsigned one is specified to work modulo 2^n_bits