# Surprising result when reading int_fast8_t from std::cin

Tags: c++, iostream, cstdint

I am trying to build a simple cpp code to check whether an input number is an even number bigger than 2 (trying to experimentally solve codeforce's watermelon using cstdint). Problem is, when i use int_fast8_t as the data type for the input interger, the code somehow prints "yes" when i put in 2 as an input. This problem is nonexistent when I use basic int data type. Any ideas on why this happens?

the code is as below:

```
#include <cstdint>
#include <iostream>

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    int_fast8_t input;
    std::cin >> input;

    if ((input % 2 == 0) && (input > 2)) {
        std::cout << "YES";
    } else {
        std::cout << "NO";
    } std::cout << "\n";

    return 0;
}
```

```
input: 2

expected output: NO
actual output  : YES
```

Comment: Check the `sizeof(input)`. What fundamental type has that size?

Comment: its becuase that type is almost cetainly char (it is in my test) so you are inputting a char not a int and '2' is greater than 2

Comment: debug the program and you'll realize the value of `input` immediately after reading it. Learning how to use a debugger is a required skill going forward [What is a debugger and how can it help me diagnose problems?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25385173/995714)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that `int_fast8_t` is defined as a type alias for `signed char`. This isn't required by the C++ standard, but it's what your standard library chose to do.

You could verify this by looking at the source code of your standard library, or with:

```cpp
static_assert(std::is_same_v<std::int_fast8_t, signed char>>);
```

As a result, what you're actually doing is:

```cpp
signed char input;
std::cin >> input;
```

This calls [`operator>>(std::istream&, signed char&)`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/operator_gtgt2), which is a special overload that treats `signed char` like a character, instead of an integer.

When providing `2` as user input, this is actually the ASCII/UTF-8 character `'2'`, which has the numeric value `50`.

This passes the test `input % 2 == 0` because `50` is divisible by `2`, and also passes the test `input > 2` because `50` is greater than `2`.

#### Solution

To fix this, use `int` instead; at least for user input.

#### See Also

- [uint8_t can't be printed with cout](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19562103/5740428) (same problem, different type alias)

Comment: oh, I see, do you happen to know where the alias is defined? Any way on how to use int_fast8_t as an integer data type in this situation?

Comment: @Oportunitas the type aliases are defined in `<cstdint>`. In most standard libraries, this header (see [libstdc++](https://github.com/gcc-mirror/gcc/blob/master/libstdc%2B%2B-v3/include/tr1/cstdint)) includes from a compiler-generated header, so you don't really get to see the definitions in code.