# Ambiguous calls to class constructors

Tags: c++, constructor, ambiguity

I am currently implementing a custom string class, but I am facing some issues with the class constructors. The class is a custom wrapper for std::string, so the class have most of the std::string constructors, except for the iterators constructors since some systems where the code will run does not support STL.

The class also provides some constructors based on Arduino String implementation, specifically the numeric variables to string constructors, which are shown below:

Number Conversion Constructors:

```
// unsigned int
    string(const uint8_t Source, uint8_t Base =  10, bool LetterCase = CPString::NumberConversion::LetterCase::Mode);
    string(const uint16_t Source, uint8_t Base = 10, bool LetterCase = CPString::NumberConversion::LetterCase::Mode);
    string(const uint32_t Source, uint8_t Base = 10, bool LetterCase = CPString::NumberConversion::LetterCase::Mode);
    string(const uint64_t Source, uint8_t Base = 10, bool LetterCase = CPString::NumberConversion::LetterCase::Mode);

// signed int
    string(const int8_t Source, uint8_t Base = 10, bool LetterCase = CPString::NumberConversion::LetterCase::Mode, bool IntFormat = CPString::NumberConversion::IntFormat::Mode);
    string(const int16_t Source, uint8_t Base = 10, bool LetterCase = CPString::NumberConversion::LetterCase::Mode, bool IntFormat = CPString::NumberConversion::IntFormat::Mode);
    string(const int32_t Source, uint8_t Base = 10, bool LetterCase = CPString::NumberConversion::LetterCase::Mode, bool IntFormat = CPString::NumberConversion::IntFormat::Mode);
    string(const int64_t Source, uint8_t Base = 10, bool LetterCase = CPString::NumberConversion::LetterCase::Mode, bool IntFormat = CPString::NumberConversion::IntFormat::Mode);

// float
    explicit string(const float Source);
    string(const float Source, uint8_t precision);
```

As a simple brief: Base represents the number base to be used to convert the variable, where 2 would be binary, 8 octal, and 16 hex, the usable number bases are [2,32]. And LetterCase is a variable that defines if upper case or lower case lettering should be used.

The problem is that this set of contructors become ambiguous with one of the std::string contructors, specifically the fill constructor, (below the definition):

```
string(unsigned int n, char c);
```

When calling:

```
CPString::string myString(10,'a');
```

The compiler throws error C2666: overloaded functions have similar conversion

I assume that the char literal is being cast to uint8_t, is it possible to unambiguiate this constructors? I know that changing 10 to 10u unambiguates the call, but I want to find a better solution. That would also accept 10 as a first parameter for the fill constructor.

Comment: Related: [uint8_t can't be printed with cout](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19562103)

Comment: Let me pose this example: `CPString::string myString(10,' ');` where the fill character is the space character. The space character's numeric value is 32. Should this be "create a string with 10 spaces" or "convert 10 to base 32"?

Comment: I see, I think then that the best solution would be to expose one set of constructors, possibly the numeric conversions as separate class methods instead of constructors

Comment: @JaMiT `uint8_t` can't be `char`, because `char` is not considered an _unsigned integer type_ which `uint8_t` is required to be.

Comment: @JaMiT Sorry, I meant to say that they may not cover all standard integer types, of course.

Comment: @ChecheRomo Overloading on type aliases such as (u)intXX_t is already wrong. There is no guarantee that they cover all integer types. Overloading over all integer types should be done with a SFINAE'ed or constrained template or by overloading on the fundamental integer types (short, int, long, long long etc.) which are guaranteed to be distinct types. Also, the integer type `char` will not be covered by your overloads.

Comment: STL is dead. Long live the standard library.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem you're facing is that the fixed width integer types are aliases, not separate types. Often, `uint8_t` is just another name for `unsigned char`. A different name, not a different type.

One solution that also increases readability is to introduce a scoped enumeration. For example:

```cpp
enum class Base : uint8_t {
    Base2 = 2,
    Base3,
    Base4,
    Base5,
    Base6,
    // ...
    // You get the idea, I hope
    // ...
    Base31,
    Base32
};
```

This `Base` type is distinct from all other types, yet it's the same size as `uint8_t`. Using this as the second parameter to the "Number Conversion Constructors" would keep the signatures basically the same, but they would no longer be ambiguous, and the call sites would be easier to read (`Base16` says that it is a base more clearly than `16`).

Comment: "_Changing the second parameter of your "Number Conversion Constructors" to something larger than a char, such as unit16_t, should resolve the ambiguity._": That will either not resolve the ambiguity.

Comment: But it won't resolve that ambiguity either. The wanted overload still needs the conversion on the first argument (`int` -> `unsigned int`), while there exist overloads that do not require it in the other set of overloads. That's enough to make the wanted overload impossible to be the best viable.

Comment: I'm going to give it a try with enums, I think that it also indeed helps with code readability, while mantaining the functionality I require, thanks!

Comment: Tested it and worked all fine, only I don't like the redundancy on Base::BaseX invocation of the enum class, I'll have to think of proper naming, I think I'll go with NumberBases::BaseX thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You could set the parameter's type to `auto` and use `std::is_same<char&, decltype(parameter)>()` or `std::is_same<char, decltype(parameter)>()` for char, and `std::is_same<uint8_t&, decltype(parameter)>()` or
`std::is_same<uint8_t decltype(parameter)>()` for unsigned char.

Correct me if I am wrong.